# Flatten MATLAB structure using dynamic structure reference in single line

Tags: matlab, structure

I have the following structure:

```
myStruct.A.var = 'abc';
myStruct.B.var = '123';
myStruct.C.var = 7;
...
```

I am looking for a compact (1-2 lines) way of flattening the structure in order to get all the values of the 'var' subfields as:

```
flattened_var = {'abc', '123', 7}
```

For example, something like the below lines (which sadly do not work):

```
inBetweenFields = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
flattened_var   = myStruct.(inBetweenFields{:}).var;
```

Comment: Why does it have to be 1-2 lines?

Comment: For the sake of compactness.

Comment: @ChrisOreinos Typically readability is preferred over brevity unless there is a performance benefit.

Comment: What about [struct2cell](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html) ?

Comment: Are you programming for twitter that you have a 140 character limit or so? It's not 1970 anymore, where every bit you sent to the Voyager satellite counts. MATLAB can handle a tad more code without problems.

Comment: @Adriaan: I don't understand the point of your comment. Everything in MATLAB can be expanded to many lines of code, but some things can be done in a compact and elegant way. This is why I asked if there is a compact solution to my problem. I asked "how to", I didn't ask "should I". Your sarcasm concerning Twitter and Voyager is irrelevant.

Comment: As @Suever pointed out, compactness is rarely worth the benefit in modern programming languages, as in general those codes are slower than other, lengthier solutions. See Excaza's answer, his loop is 6 lines, but much faster than the shorter `cellfun`. Your question sounds like you're willing to sacrifice everything for being as short as possible, which is more like code golf, or indeed, Twitter.

Comment: @Adriaan : This is a matter of preference. Yes, there are points in my code which perform small, computationally insignificant tasks. For those segments I stylistically prefer more compact code. In other words, I don't want to use 2 more variable names ('substructs' and 'nsubs' in excaza's solution) plus one loop for an operation which only has a minor role in my code.

Comment: Sure, that's your perfect right to do. Most people, however, don't like to do that because if at some point in the future you need a similar piece of code but for much, much larger data, you'll be glad of a bit of time saving. Also, if you don't like those variables, just `clear nsubs substructs` after the loop. (Yes, there's an extra line for that, but at least you'll free up memory).

Comment: @ChrisOreinos If you're worried about compactness, why not put the code that does "the heavy lifting" in a separate function (possibly within the same script) and only leave 1 line like `flattened_var = flattenStruct(var)` where it "matters visually"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple loop is more than adequate:

```
% Set up data
myStruct.A.var = 'abc';
myStruct.B.var = '123';
myStruct.C.var = 7;

% Extract data
substructs = fieldnames(myStruct);  % Get substructure names
nsubs = numel(substructs);  % Get number of substructures
flatteneddata = cell(nsubs, 1);  % Preallocate cell array

% Extract data
for ii = 1:nsubs
    flatteneddata{ii} = myStruct.(substructs{ii}).var;
end
```

This can also be made Twitter compatible with [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), which is very nearly always slower than the equivalent loop.

```
% Set up data
myStruct.A.var = 'abc';
myStruct.B.var = '123';
myStruct.C.var = 7;

flatteneddata = cellfun(@(x) myStruct.(x).var, fieldnames(myStruct), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Both approaches generate the desired output:

```
flatteneddata =

  3×1 cell array

    'abc'
    '123'
    [  7]
```

Comment: Much +1 for the twitter compatible solution. That's like code-golf, but then in text messages :D

Comment: @(x) liked your Tweet

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
cellfun(@struct2cell,struct2cell(myStruct))
```

Comment: @ Adriaan I can be wrong, but this solution seems to work without the parameter 'UniformOutPut',0

Comment: @Adriaan I tested in octave here is an online demo: http://rextester.com/DQEF8827

Comment: @rahnema1 : The problem in your approach is that if the struct has other fields which are not of interest, say if myStruct.A.anotherVar = 'ghj', then the nested struct2cell calls will flatten the struct without distinguishing between 'var' or 'anotherVar' node fieldnames.

Comment: @ChrisOreinos It is better to add any `additional condition`  to the original question to get a proper answer